# C macro function has the same output of equivalent normal function, but the algorithm has a different output

Tags: c, macros

So I've got a function that has the same definition as a macro function, and they output the same value. To confirm this, I did this:

```
int a(int vertex, int offset) {
      int value = vertex*numberOfoffsets + offset;
      if (value != b(vertex, offset)) printf("error\n");
      return value;
}
```

Here's the macro:

```
#define b(vertex, offset) (vertex*numberOfoffsets + offset)  //EDIT: I had mta instead of b here (on the stackoverflow post)
```

Note that `numberOfOffsets` is also a macro itself, which returns 6.
I ran the algorithm using `a(vertex,offset)` and everything works as expected, with no `error\n` printed, which means both functions return the same value.

But when I run the algorithm with `b(vertex,offset)` instead of `a(vertex,offset)`, a wrong answer comes out (although the algorithm doesn't break.

Is there anything that I'm missing regarding macros? Don't they just replace text? I don't really understand this behavior.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to change the name of the fuction, b is now correct (it's the define function)

EDIT2: Adding parentheses fixes the problem, so it should be:

```
#define b(vertex, offset) (((vertex)*(numberOfoffsets)) + (offset))
```

But other users suggested that I used inline functions instead, so now it's:

```
static __inline__
int b(int vertex, int offset) {
  return vertex*numberOfoffsets + offset;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call the function?

Comment: What is `b` here?

Comment: please show all your code, whats `b`. you never use mta so its seems irrelevant. You are saying "this code gives the wrong answer" but dont show the code, the input or the answer

Comment: Typically, you should use an excessive number of parentheses in the macro definition, e.g. `#define mta(v,o,n) ((v)*(n) + (o))`

Comment: Macro is not the function. It only replaces textually something with something else before the compilation. Macro does not return anything. Avoid using this kind of macros if possible (almost always  it is). If you want to avoid function calls - use inline functions instead. Macros are error prone and very difficult to debug

Comment: You are neither giving a literal nor a variable into "vertex" or into "numberOfoofsets", are you? If one of those is a sum you have paved your path to failure. See comment by user3386109.

Comment: Post definition of `numberOfoffsets`.

Comment: Posting the values used in `a(int vertex, int offset)` helps along with the expected and actual results.  Please update.  Leaving those off makes the question less clear and more open to consideration of many things (perhaps irrelevant).  Save us  time with more info.

Comment: With `int a(int vertex, int offset) {
      int value = vertex*numberOfoffsets + offset;`, `vertex*numberOfoffsets + offset` is computed using the wider of `int` and type of `numberOfoffsets` math.  With the macro, `(vertex*numberOfoffsets + offset)` uses `intmax_t` math.

Comment: @melpomene b is supposed to be the old mta

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I wanted to switch the functions to macros because I need the program to be as quick as possible, since the function can be called more than a million times. Does this not save time? The function basically only translates a matrix index to a array index.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html#Inline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you should use an excessive number of parentheses in macro definitions, e.g.

```
#define b(vertex, offset) ((vertex) * 6 + (offset))
```

Otherwise, operator precedence can change the result to something unintended. For example, calling the macro with

```
int x = 4;
int y = b(x+1, 3);
```

should be the same as `y = 5 * 6 + 3 = 33`. However, without the  parentheses the result is
 `y = 4 + 1*6 + 3 = 13`.

---

There is another difference between macros and functions as [@jxh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315052/jxh) pointed out in the comments.

When the function that takes `int` parameters is called, and the parameters aren't of type `int`, the compiler will implicitly convert the parameters to `int`. But with a macro, no such conversions are made.

For example, the code

```
#define b(vertex, offset) ((vertex) * 6 + (offset))

int a(int vertex, int offset)
{
    return vertex * 6 + offset;
}

int main(void)
{
    double vertex = 3.3;
    double offset = 7.4;
    int resultA = a(vertex, offset);
    int resultB = b(vertex, offset);
    printf("%d %d\n", resultA, resultB);
}
```

will print `25 27`. That's because the compiler converts `vertex` to 3 and `offset` to `7` before calling the function. But the macro does the math with `double` values, and the answer is converted to an `int` by the assignment to `resultB`.

It's debatable whether you need to do anything about that. However, to make the macro exactly equivalent to the function, you could write it as

```
#define b(vertex, offset) ((int)((int)(vertex) * 6 + (int)(offset)))
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil otherwise your keyboard will wear out faster. It is better to have too many than to have one pair missing.

Comment: This was definitely. I had the extra parenthesis outside thinking it would be enough but it wasn't. It's working now, thank you!

Comment: @Myntekt Cool, glad I could help :)

Comment: There is also a possibility the function computes as `int`, while the macro could be computing at a higher precision.

Comment: @jxh I'm not exactly sure what that means but they both return the same value when called, so the problem might be when it's called next to other operations and the priority get messed up as the other guy suggested

Comment: @Myntekt I'll add an explanation to the answer that responds to the comment by  @[jxh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315052/jxh).

Comment: @user3386109 I understand what he meant now. That was not the problem since the numbers are always ints, but it could have been. Thank you for your help